# Where do I set administrator password for phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-10.04

I'm trying to install phpMyAdmin on my Ubuntu 10.04 server, by doing 'apt-get install phpmyadmin'. Installer asks me for MySQL administrator password and for phpMyAdmin database user password, but not for phpMyAdmin root user password. How do I obtain/reset this password to access my newly installed server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow you. The phpMyAdmin root user is the MySQL root user. So whatever your MySQL username/password is, that's what you use to log in as root in phpMyAdmin. Do you have a root password for MySQL? If not, set it like this:

`mysqladmin -u root password [insert-password-here]`

Comment: Thanks, you did follow me perfectly. I just thought you need another user for phpMyAdmin ::)

Comment: @Septagram No problem. I always assume that I'm misunderstanding something initially and seek to find out more information. Glad it was a simple "fix". =)